# Python(parser) instead of Pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want pylint to help me fix errors instead of Python parser. It was Jedi before this and Pylance before that. I'm looking everywhere to find a way so pylint is my linter and any error I make in my code is highlighted by pylint and not these. Any fix? I have selected pylint as my linter from the Command palette and have added this in my json.settings:

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
```

but still it doesn't work. Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to disable the linting of Pylance for now. Some people have asked a similar [question](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/818) on GitHub. You could have a look at it.